# Law of Conservation of Angular Momentum

Tags: cosmology, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

Suppose the earth orbits the sun in a perfectly circular path and no other celestial bodies are present. Now, its distance from the sun is doubled. Now,what will be its new T? Applying Kepler's law: T^2 proportional to R^3. This yields a value of T. but if we apply Conservation law of angular momentum, it yields different T.Show full calculation using conservation plz.

Comment: Dear friends, I have changed the question a bit. please, have a fresh review kindly. thanks

Answer (score 2):

What?

Conservation of angular momentum will tell you nothing. It basically states that

$mrv=const.$

(since the radius is always perpendicular to $v$ in a circulat motion), and, as $r$ and $m$ are always the same, then $v$ is also the same, which was obvious.

So conservation of $\vec{L}$ doesn't tell you much information.

Instead try using that the gravitational force is the same as the centripetal one  $F_g = F_c$. Then you'll get the value of $v$.

And if you use the definition of velocity as $\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$, then you'll get Kepler's third law, with exactly

$$T^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{GM}r^3$$

Answer (score 0):

The angular momentum of a circular orbit varies with R. Your assumption is, implictly, that it is independent of R.